# What are good places to mine solid amounts of iron ore?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been using Transmute Mineral Ore a lot (after discovering how much it helps level the Smithing skill) and was wondering: where are some good locations for harvesting iron ore?
I'm aware of Halted Stream Camp's massive supply, but are there any other decent iron ore locations like it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other big locations I remember were in [Fort Fellhammer](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Fort_Fellhammer) and [Knifepoint Ridge](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Knifepoint_Ridge).

As user *teair* commented above, [here](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Iron#Mineral_Sources) is a link where you can find more detailed information about where to find iron ore.

Comment: The other thing I do is every time I go to the shops to redeem my loot for gold, I just buy all the ore the shopkeepers have. Iron costs only ~4g for my lvl 40 guy, and I had about 200 ore until I built a house.